# object sent from ts frontend to java backend transforms into LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, spring, typescript, rest

I have a typescript frontend communicating with my java backend over REST. I just added another simple rest endpoint but sending the object to the backend and trying to cast it properly doesn't work because the sent body is a linkedHashMap?

**service.ts**

```
createEvent(event: CustomerEvent): Observable<HttpResponse<CustomerEvent>> {
    return this.http.post<CustomerEvent>(this.eventUrl, event, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

**customer-event-model.ts**

```
export class CustomerEvent {
    constructor(public customer: ICustomer, public event: String) {}
}
```

**customer.model.ts**

```
export interface ICustomer {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    address?: string;
}

export class Customer implements ICustomer {
    constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string, public email?: string, public address?: string) {}
}
```

**Rest**

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> addCustomerEvent(@RequestBody Object customerEvent) {
  log.info("~REST request to create new event " + customerEvent.toString());
  CustomerEvent e = (CustomerEvent) customerEvent; // <<---- FAILS cannot cast LinkedHashMap to CustomerEvent
}
```

Why is it sending a LinkedHashMap?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

`@RequestBody CustomerEvent customerEvent`

As this will allow spring to deserialize the request body to a CustomerEvent object instance.

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Comment: this is what I did and it deserializes the customer in correctly but not the event. it always stays null.